# Quarkus fails when pulling image from docker registry

Tags: quarkus, testcontainers, podman

I installed podman on windows, i run

```
quarkus dev
```

but i got

> Database for default datasource (oracle) starting: 2023-09-29
> 12:20:32,855 INFO  [org.tes.uti.RegistryAuthLocator] (build-22)
> Failure when attempting to lookup auth config. Please ignore if you
> don't have images in an authenticated registry. Details:
> (dockerImageName: docker.io/gvenzl/oracle-free:latest, configFile:
> C:\Users\my_user\.docker\config.json, configEnv: DOCKER_AUTH_CONFIG).
> Falling back to docker-java default behaviour. Exception message:
> Status 404: No config supplied. Checked in order:
> C:\Users\my_user.docker\config.json (file not found),
> DOCKER_AUTH_CONFIG (not set)

if i run :

```
> podman login docker.io
Authenticating with existing credentials for docker.io
Existing credentials are valid. Already logged in to docker.io
```

actually i notice that there is no configFile: C:\Users\my_user\.docker\config.json
probably because podman use another format to store credential...

So how can i do if i want to continue to use quarkus with podman ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem setting env var DOCKER_AUTH_CONFIG with the content of podman file auth.json  (you find it inside ~.config\containers )

```
SET DOCKER_AUTH_CONFIG={"auths": {"docker.io": {"auth": "...."}}}
```